# Error CS0120 UnityEngine.Collider.Raycast(UnityEngine.Ray, out UnityEngine.RaycastHit, float)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am getting the error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.Collider.Raycast(UnityEngine.Ray, out UnityEngine.RaycastHit, float)'

I have read a question where someone seemed to have the same/similar problem but I weren't able to fix the problem with the solutions i saw.

Sorry if the question seems repetitive.

```
public class TileMouseOver : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
public Color highlightColor;
[SerializeField]
Color normalColor;

void Start() {
    normalColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
}


void Update () {

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(  Input.mousePosition );
    RaycastHit hitInfo;

    if( Collider.Raycast( ray, out hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity )) {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = highlightColor;
    } else {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = normalColor;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Collider.Raycast` is not a static method, you need an instance of the `Collider` class. e.g. `var c = new Collider(); c.Raycast(....);`

Comment: @DavidG This fixed the issue, thanks for the help :)